# Replace &#39; and similar html codes with their correspondent character?

Tags: php

so I have a string that goes like this:

```
$string = "This is a test string. It has characters like these: &#39;";
```

Is there a php function that transforms these to their correspondent character, in my example the desired output would be:

```
print $string
// OUTPUT: This is a test string. It has characters like these: '
```

Comment: So the function has to remove the `t` too?

Comment: @Musa Oops, sorry that was a mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes there is:
`htmlspecialchars_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES);`

not sure about the specific `&#39;` char, as far as I know `htmlspecialchars` (with `ENT_QUOTES` flag) convert an apostrophe (') to `&#039;` (with a leading zero)

so the exact behavior on `&#39;` worth checking

EDIT:
I made the test and it does work :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

It's like reverse htmlentities. If you use quotes in your input string you have to set the second parameter of `html_entity_decode()` to `ENT_QUOTES`

See it in action: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f4649eb47a8e639c514787a100b63bbad4bc8c6